# Reference Request : about inverse problem in PDE

Tags: reference-request

In your opinion what is the best book to start Inverse problem which starts with simple explanations.

My goal is to understand the problem inverse for the wave equation .

Thank you in advance

Comment: You haven’t told us anything about your background in analysis and other relevant areas of mathematics.  You also haven’t told us much about you want to learn other than that you are interested inverse scattering problems involving the wave equation.  Are you interested in analytical results? Numerical methods?

Comment: Dear @BrianBorchers , Thank you for your interest , I would like to read about both aspects (analytical resulat and numerical methods ).and I would like to take a look at some open problem.for my level I think I'm good in the analysis I just have some problem with the manifolds

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the book of M. Bellassoued and M. Yamamoto : Carleman Estimates and Applications to Inverse Problems for Hyperbolic Systems. This is a recent and good book which treats inverse problems from analytical approach by Carleman estimate approach.